# WSO2 Api Manager Data Mapper does not work

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, datamapper

I have installed wso2 Api Manager, and wso2 Api Manager tooling extensions.

I wonder if the datamapper does work in the v2.0.0 of the Api Manager.

It is currently included in the wso2 am solution, but it does not work in my case.

I see my sequence as "sucessfully saved", but unfortunately unable to actually save it : The logs are saying that the XML sequence are not found for the datamapper, regarding the apache-synapse configuration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data mapper will not work with API Manager 2.0.0 since it went out with ESB 5.0.0 which was released after API Manager 2.0.0.

However, with API Manager 2.1.0 you will be able to use datamapper by installing datamapper mediator Aggrigrate from the P2 repository explicitly into the product. API Manager 2.1.0 is already released. And the P2 repository will be ready to use by the coming week.

Comment: Thanks! I am looking forward :)

Comment: P2 repo with API Manager 2.1.0 features is released now. You can install datamapper mediator feature by following http://chamaleedesilva.blogspot.com/2017/02/how-to-install-datamapper-mediator-in.html. If you need to use API Manager 2.0.0 itself follow the same steps in the blog with installing the features with mediation version 4.6.6 and org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine_4.6.6.jar from the nexus repo.